# How to forward selective web traffic to the VPN tunnel in Window SSTP VPN while the split tunnel is on?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to setup SSTP VPN with split tunnel, and I want to allow some web traffic to go through the VPN tunnel. Is there a way to specify what traffic go through the VPN tunnel and what go through the regular network. Also, the SSTP VPN is setup in window server 2012.

Comment: I don't think you can do this for "web" traffic. You could define routes and set IP ADDRESSES destinations that would go via vpn or regular network.

Comment: How would I define routes with specific IP address destination?

Comment: depends on the platform.

In windows: check the interfaces index: netsh int ipv4 show interfaces
route -p add <destination> mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 IF <X>

destination would be the IP/netmask you want to route and X the index of the interface from the netsh command

In linux, it can vary from distro to distro, but I have this as a post-up script:
ip route add <destination> via 192.168.40.13 dev <interface name>